# Jodit Uploader option to support image max file size

Tags: jodit

**Expected behaviour:** An Image option to restrict image by max file size property when an image is uploaded.

**Actual behaviour:**   Currently there is no such option to restrict the image upload by file size.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround option might be detecting content size using javascript:

```
if (editor.getEditorValue().length > (1024 * 1024 * 1.37))
{
   alert('content too big: ' + (editor.getEditorValue().length / (1024 * 1024 * 1.37)).toFixed(2) + ' MB');
   return;
}
```

This can be triggered when saving (custom code) or using [jodit events](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/docs/modules/event_emitter.html#jodit-event-emitter)